# How to detect Add button presses in PKAddPassesViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to detect when the users tap on the "Add" button in the `PKAddPassesViewController`.

[image]

I added `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish()` so that when `passVC` is dismissed, function `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish()` will be called.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         self.pass = try PKPass(data: downloadedData! as Data)
         let passVC = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: self.pass)
         self.present(passVC!, animated: true)
         // when passVC is dimissed by the user,     addPassesViewControllerDidFinish is expected to be called, but it never gets called.

    }

    func addPassesViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKAddPassesViewController) {
        print("enter DidFinish")
        let passLib = PKPassLibrary()

        // Get your pass
        guard let pass = self.pass else { return }

        if passLib.containsPass(pass) {
            print("if start")

            // Show alert message for example
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Successfully added to Wallet", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))

            controller.show(alertController, sender: nil)
            print("if end")

        } else {
            // Cancel button pressed
            print("else start");
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("else end");
        }
    }
```

However, when passVC is dimissed by the user, func `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish()` never gets called at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things you should fix: 
1. Extend PKAddPassesViewControllerDelegate in your ViewController class. 
2. Double check if you added `delegate` to your PKAddPassesViewController: `VC?.delegate = self`, which will link your delegate to PKAddPassesViewControllerDelegate. 
3. Inside `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish`, dismiss `controller` first. Then do whatever you want inside `passLib.containPass`. The alertController is no longer belonged to the `controller`, maybe to its parent view.